# How to use the Docker golang client package to connect over TCP?

Tags: docker, go

I am prototyping a Go application that will ultimately talk to a remote Docker host. To this end I am using Docker's Go client package (docs at https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/client).

The environment is Ubuntu 19.10 in VirtualBox 6.1.4, using Docker 19.03.6, and Go 1.14. All Go packages have been installed with go get in the last 72 hours.
For local testing purposes I am trying to connect to a local Docker host at tcp://0.0.0.0:2375. That is, I am running

`sudo dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`

With this, commands such as

`docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 ps`

and

`curl -k -v -i http://0.0.0.0:2375/v1.40/containers/json`

both work, and I am able to observe the traffic over port 2375 with Wireshark.

However, attempting to do the same thing through the Go client package fails with

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://0.0.0.0:2375. Is the docker daemon running?

and nothing shows up in Wireshark.
Here is the example Go code :

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
)

func main() {
    cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.WithHost("tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"), client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error: could not create docker client handle")
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    options := types.ContainerListOptions{}
    data, err := cli.ContainerList(context.Background(), options)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error: could not request containers list")
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(data)
    }
}
```

Attempts to set the environment variables `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`, `DOCKER_CERT_PATH=`, and `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=`, then configure the client handle through `client.FromEnv()` also failed in the exact same way.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Exposing the Docker port over TCP at all is a _major_ mistake: anyone who can reach the port at all can almost trivially root the host.  If your system is acting at all suspicious, consider whether it might have been compromised and needs to be reinstalled.  There's a complex TLS setup that can make it safe, if you get it right, but it'd be better to stick to strictly local-socket access to Docker.

Comment: @DavidMaze  As I said in the question, this is for local testing of a prototype inside a VM. The final product _will_ be sending API calls to a properly secured docker host on the company's internal infrastructure. I am simply trying to work out why the Golang SDK provided by docker fails over TCP.

Comment: @MatthiasPercelay I just used your code and it worked for me for a remote docker host.